# if, elif, else statements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help with the exit() function and the if, else, and elif functions. when i press enter without typing in the first name and gets prompted to type in the name again the message comes back as if i still didnt enter a name. same with the year born. and the exit() function keeps exiting out even though i entered a name the second time.

```
userName = input("\nWhat is your name? ")

if userName == "": 
    input("\nPlease Enter your name: ")
else:
    if userName == "":
        print("\nName is missing, exiting program\n")(exit())

if userName.upper() == "STEVE":
        print("\nYou are the instructor")
else:
    print("\nHi " + userName + "." + " You are a student")


userYear = input("What year were you born? ")

if userYear.isnumeric() == False:
    input("\nPlease enter your birth year with all numbers: ")
else:   
    if userYear == "":
        input("\nYou never told me when you were born! ")



userCity = input("\nWhat city do you live in? ")

if userCity.lower() == "fresno" or userCity.lower() == "bakersfield":
     print("\ni'm sorry it's so hot where you live ")
else:
    print("\nHope you like it in " + userCity +
          " \nIt must be a good life for people born in " + userYear)
```

Prompt the user for their first name with "What is your name?"

If the first name is blank (i.e. the user presses the enter key
but did not enter anything), prompt them again to enter their 
first name with "Please Enter your name"

If the user entered a blank again, then display the following 
message and exit the program...

"Name is missing, exiting program"
then skip 2 lines on the console and exit the program.

Assuming the program has not exited, check to see if the name
entered is "Steve".   Do a case-insensitive comparison so that
all the various capitalizations of "Steve" would be seen as True
(e.g. "steve", "Steve", "STEVE", etc.)

If the name is "Steve", then display "You are the instructor",
otherwise display "Hi (name entered) You are a student"

Prompt the user for "What year were you born?"

Check to see if birth year entered is not numeric (or if it is blank)

If so, prompt the user with "Please enter your birth year with all numbers"
and proceed to #10 below  (skip #9)

If not so, proceed to #9 below

Prompt the user with "What city do you live in?"

Check the city value entered to see if it is either "Fresno" or
"Bakersfield" (case-insensitive) and...if so, display "I'm sorry it's so hot where you live"]... if not, display "Hope you like it in (city entered)"

Check to see if the birth year is blank and if so, display "You never told me when you were born!" if not, display "It must be a good life for people born in (birth year entered)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` loops to achieve this nicely.

For example:

```
username = ''

while username == '':
    input('\nPlease Enter your name: ')
```

This will continually ask them to input their name until they enter a real name (any string that's not `''`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using a loop for this.

i.e.

```
userName = input("\nWhat is your name? ")

if userName == "": 
    input("\nPlease Enter your name: ")
else:
    if userName == "":
        print("\nName is missing, exiting program\n")
        exit()
```

Only takes input the first time you ask for it (i.e.) line 1:

You should find that if you enter '`steve`' on the input after a blank the program proceeds incorrectly.

Maybe replace the top with:

```
username = ""
while (username == ""):
      username = input("What is your name? ")
```

I'd also add that python support sthe elif statement, use this instead of `else: if:`

Comment: I don't need the loop because if the user does not enter their name the first time asked then they will be asked to enter their name again but in different wording. and if they do not enter their name the third time then the output will be name is missing, exiting program.

Comment: In this case, it still doesnt seem that you're doing anything with the second 'input' call, try allocating it to a variable like in the very first line!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and reuse you code like below

```py
def take_input(field_name):
    while True:
        inp = input("please enter %s"%field_name)
        if len(inp)>1:
            return inp



input_fields = ["name", "year"]
user_inputs = {}
for field in input_fields:
    user_inputs[field] = take_input(field)

print(user_inputs)
```